# How to revert string.replaceAll to it original form in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to implement JavaScript code for spelling check, where I want to perform text normalization which remove multiple whitespace before check spelling. However, in order to keep original text unchanged, I need to revert my normalization back to original text and readjust typo index.

I need to normalize, so I can cache the result and no need to run spelling check again next time. I just need to load the result from cache.

Here the following three steps:

1. Replace multiple whitespace "    " with only one " ".

```js
    // "I      lik cat." -> "I lik cat"
    // "I lik       cat." -> "I lik cat"
    const regex = / +/ig;
    "I      lik cat.".replaceAll(regex, ' ')
    "I lik       cat.".replaceAll(regex, ' ')
```

2. Find location of word in cleaned text.

```js
    // "lik" start index is 2.
    let regexp = /lik/g;
    let str = 'I lik cat.';
    let start_index = [];
    let matches = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
    matches.forEach((match) => {
       start_index.push(match.index);
    });
```

3. Revert cleaned code back to its original form and re-adjust start index accordingly.

```js
    "I lik cat" -> "I      lik cat.", start_index = 6
    "I lik cat" -> "I lik       cat.", start_index = 2
```

I'm still struggling to find a solution for reverting normalized text to original?

Comment: Why do you need to normalize the whitespace before spell check?

Comment: Can't you just store the original text in a variable somewhere and do the operation on its copy to preserve the original text?

Comment: @Barmar I need to normalize, so I can cache the result and no need to run spelling check again next time. I just need to load the result from cache.

Comment: What's the point of caching?  Surely it is just as expensive to search your cache for long string matches as it is to do the spell check again.  After all, you'd have to make sure the whole string matches.

Comment: @TimRoberts because it is grammar spell checking include. And the process consume more resource than cache.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a spell check with highlighting errors, you really don't need to worry about spaces. For my answer, I use replace with a regex to replace the string wrapped in the mark tag and set a new variable to that value. This keeps the original string intact.

```js
const output = document.querySelector(".output");
const original = document.querySelector(".original");
const regexp = /(lik)/ig;

let str = "I lik C                   AT. A                      cat I lik.";

original.innerHTML = str;

const newOutput = str.replace(regexp,"<mark>$1</mark>"); 
output.innerHTML = newOutput;
```

```css
mark {
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="original"></div>
```